# Problem with If Statement in Ruby Program

Tags: ruby

I'm super beginner to ruby, but for some reason my if statement isn't working. Whenever the name 'Cristina' is entered, the program continues to print "Hello there".

```
def Cus_free_makers_eg1heChallenge(str)
  str = gets
  if str == "Cristina"
    print "Hello Cristina!"
  else
    print "Hello there!"
  end
  return str
end
```

Comment: Change it to `if str == "Christina\n"`. After the `gets`, the string will have a terminating newline. More sensible would be maybe a `if /Christina/ =~ str`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [`strip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-strip) to remove newline:

```
str = gets.strip
if str == "Cristina" 
  print "Hello Cristina!"
else
  print "Hello there!"
end
```

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work. I added an elsif statement also, but that doesn't work either..

Comment: This _does_ work. I think `chomp` is the preferred way - but both work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
str = gets.chomp

if str == "Cristina"
  print "Hello Christina!"
else
  print "Hello there!"
end

str
```

Ruby `gets` statement is usually ended with `chomp` or `chomp!` to -- you guessed it -- "chomp" aka remove the trailing newline and carriage characters. More info in Ruby doc: https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0.0/String.html#method-i-chomp

I also took the opportunity to remove `return` and also the trailing `end` as both aren't necessary.